# Why can't I create my table? Why is this FK constraint malformed?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm getting the error below when I attempt to create a table with a couple foreign keys. It goes smoothly if I only include the userID foreign key, but complains when I try to get the other foreign key in there as well. What's the deal?

```
ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'ps5_lwilkins.PhoneNumber' (errno: 150)

SQL Statement:

CREATE  TABLE `ps5_lwilkins`.`PhoneNumber` (    
  `userID` CHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
  `resumeID` CHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `number` CHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`, `resumeID`, `number`) ,
  INDEX `user_phoneNumber_fk1` (`userID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `resume_phoneNumber_fk3` (`resumeID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `user_phoneNumber_fk1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userID` )
    REFERENCES `ps5_lwilkins`.`User` (`userID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `resume_phoneNumber_fk3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`resumeID` )
    REFERENCES `ps5_lwilkins`.`Resume` (`resumeID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Here's the schema for User:

`User(userid: CHAR(25), pass: VARCHAR(25)`) `userid` is the PK

Here's the schema for Resume:

```
Resume(userID: CHAR(25), resumeID: CHAR(30)
```

few other none important attributes). PK is `(userID, resumeID)`.

Any ideas? Need more information?

Looking at other problems similar to this, I think it's somehow a malformed FK on the resumeID... but I can't see where!

I've tried several different names for the FK constraint btw.

EDIT: I don't have the privilege to perform `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

Comment: Wait! I think I know what it is! I made the primary key in Resume (userID, resumeID), so I shouldn't be able to make a foreign key dependent on the resumeID alone! *be right back*
EDIT: ... dang, I tried to make a (resumeID, userID) foreign key, but I got the same kind of error...

Comment: `I don't have the privilege to perform SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` So get a local installation going, give yourself that permission, recreate the problem and then perform that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with your comment above. You need to change this:

```
  INDEX `user_phoneNumber_fk1` (`userID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `resume_phoneNumber_fk3` (`resumeID` ASC) ,
```

and this:

```
    FOREIGN KEY (`resumeID` )
    REFERENCES `ps5_lwilkins`.`Resume` (`resumeID` )
```

to this:

```
  INDEX `phoneNumber_fks` (`userID` ASC, `resumeID` ASC) ,
```

and this:

```
    FOREIGN KEY (`userID`, `resumeID` )
    REFERENCES `ps5_lwilkins`.`Resume` (`userID`, `resumeID` )
```

Comment: Ah! I see! I followed what you said, and just did this:
CREATE  TABLE `ps5_lwilkins`.`PhoneNumber` (    
  `userID` CHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
  `resumeID` CHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `number` CHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`, `resumeID`, `number`) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`userID`, `resumeID`)
    REFERENCES `ps5_lwilkins`.`Resume` (`userID`,`resumeID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
And it worked! Thank you!